# Making dyamic threads

Tags: java

how to make dyamic threads.............in java

Comment: What does "dynamic" even mean in this context? How is "making a dynamic thread" different from "making a thread"?

Comment: it means that i can create a thread at runtime......suppose when an event is fired

Comment: so what other kinds of threads are there? Do you know of a way to create a thread at compile-time? "dynamic" is overused in some circles and can often be dropped without a replacement without altering the meaning of a question/statement.

Comment: if u know the answer then tell otherwise dont waste my time

Comment: you waste our time by writing extremely ill-defined questions and expecting good answers. Precision is a skill that's valuable for a software developer. If you don't want to learn it, it's your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean Like?

```
 new Thread();
```

I would suggest you use an [ExecutorService](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ExecutorService%20tutorial) as these are cleaner ways to handle tasks/threads.

e.g.

```
private static final ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

// in a method
es.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do a task in the background.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

At least google a bit next time before asking such a basic question: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html